# Weak convergence of function composition

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, empirical-processes

I came across the paper of van der Vaart and Wellner ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1013.pdf)). The problem I am facing is to derive the convergence of the probability integral transform to another distribution. Suppose we have two distributions of a random variable $X$, given by $F_X$ and $F_{X'}$, with regular properties, well-defined with existing PDFs. The latter can be thought of as, for instance, a distribution of $X$ conditional on some event, or simply a functional transformation of $F_X$.

Take a functional form represented by $F_X^{-1} (F_{X'})$, where the inverse is the quantile function of $X$, maping from $[0,1]$ onto a bounded set $[a,b]$. Relating to the proposed paper, can how would you derive the convergence of

$$
\sqrt{n}P\left(F_X^{-1} (\hat{F}_{X'}) - F_X^{-1} (F_{X'})\right),
$$

where $\hat{F}_{X'}$ is the empirical measure of $F_{X'}$?